# Controls (Combo, Radio, Text) in column header SWT

Tags: java, swt, tablecolumn

I've been searching everywhere, but I can't find a solution, nor an answer.

**Can custom controls/widgets be placed in a column header of a table in SWT?**

I can put those controls in the first row, but that is not the solution, because of the scrolling.

The reason for the need is because I'm importing a CSV file, but sometimes the columns in it aren't in the same order as before, so I want to give the user an option to set which column is for what (Radio Buttons or Combo).

Thank you.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334546/combo-in-columnheader-with-swt) has a proposed workaround .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Generally, you can only do something with an SWT widget if it's supported natively by all OSes and window systems SWT supports.