# Disable Clickable Header Feature in TableViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface, tableviewer

I have a SWT JFace TableViewer where the column headers are clickable. I want to disable this feature in TableViewers. I want the column header to be flat.

Any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Comment: There isn't anything to do this for the standard headers. You could just use Labels for the headers with an extended version of `TableColumnLayout` as I described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18376275/2670892)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the header from being highlighted (the header becomes blue) when you focus?

Comment: I don't think so, the header is drawn by the native control and SWT have control of this.