# How to use JFace combobox in the table header

Tags: java, swt, jface

I was able to use combo box in the cells using `setEditingSupprt()` method of `TableViewerColumn` class.

Is there any way I could do the same in the table header?

Basically, I am trying to use combo box as a filter, and so I would like to get it in the header.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Controls (Combo, Radio, Text) in column header SWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046897/controls-combo-radio-text-in-column-header-swt)

Comment: A possible workaround was suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334546/combo-in-columnheader-with-swt